# What good smelling grass grows in USDA ZONE 4A?

Tags: grass, hardiness-zone

My dad grew up in an area of Chicago, USA that a good smelling grass grew all over the yard (I think a lemon grass), and am wondering what would be a great idea to sneak into the yard to have a similar smell.

Comment: I guess when you say “lemon grass”, you don’t mean [the tropical grass used in South(east) Asian cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cymbopogon_citratus)?

Comment: Did your dad mow the lawn, and is that when it smelled best?

Comment: @Jurp I don't know, his parents never owned the house when I was alive.

Comment: @Stephie I doubt it, so I thought I would ask the experts.